# Cordova android target not installed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Im trying to set cordova on my laptop using windows 7 and I still get that message

[image: This is my nodeJs command]

Comment: Android Target meaning emulator... Have you set up an emulator?

Comment: yes but still not working

Comment: Is your emulator set in Path variable? i.e. can it be opened from commandline with `emulator` command?

Comment: android emulator already set still not working

Comment: If you see this message, you need JDK 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to Install Android SDK Packages first, Follow steps in this URL

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

then you have to set Environment Variables:

1. Set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the location of your JDK
   installation.
2. Set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to the
   location of your Android SDK installation It is also recommended
   that you add the Android SDK's tools, tools/bin, and platform-tools
   directories to your `PATH`

Comment: thanks I solved it by runing my device instead of emulator

Comment: And 4 years later these tools still think it is 1995.  Just unzip the file, then make sure you add all of the environment variables by hand.  It's like editing autoexec.bat and config.sys all over again.  end of rant.  And get off my lawn!

Comment: What file? @BobRamsey

Answer (score 0):

I'm here in the middle of 2024, as I'm maintaining a legacy project and my suggestion for anyone, who is experiencing problems configuring the Android environment for Cordova is, to

- remove the `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` variables and the others added in the configuration process,
- restarting your terminal
- and run the command `cordova requirements android`

Once you have done the installations correctly, Cordova will resolve the variables automatically.